# Waiting for multiple subscriptions on client-side cases of Meteor.startup

Tags: javascript, meteor

<strike>I think I'm hitting a race condition on my Meteor client startup code.</strike>

**Brief background**

I'm using Meteor for a HTML5 game lobby interface. When a user returns to the menu by refreshing the page or returning later, I want the client to find any games in progress for that user. However, I can't access any Collections during startup.

An excerpt from the top of my `client.js` file is shown below.

```
Meteor.subscribe("players"); //Meteor.Collection("players" references Meteor.users via user_id
Meteor.subscribe("games");  // each player has a game_id, linked to Meteor.Collection("games"
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
      //find the player from the user_id, find game from player.game_id
      var current_user_id = Meteor.userId();
      var playerFromUser = Players.findOne({"user_id":current_user_id});
      if(typeof playerFromUser !== 'undefined'){
          var getGame = Games.findOne(playerFromUser.game_id);
          if(typeof getGame !== 'undefined'){
              alert('game found!'); //is not reached
          }else{
              alert('game not found'); //is not reached
          }
       }else{
          alert('player not found'); //*********** IS reached. Why? *********** 
       }
  });
}
```

However, from the javascript console I can run `Players.findOne({"user_id":Meteor.userId());` and it can return a valid Player just fine. <strike>What's up with this race condition with my collections?</strike>

**EDIT 1:**

Looking deeper into the library I see that I was incorrectly assuming the data from the server would be immediately available.  The subscriptions actually take a while to process, which was why they aren't available right when the client starts. I'm updating my question to express this new information.

**Updated Question**

Since I rely on multiple subscriptions to find a game for a user (both Players and Games), is there a Meteor way to wait for both? Having a separate subscription just for getting a possible game in progress seems wrong. So does requiring any server call at all.

I feel should be able to find the game I need from the retrieved players and games once they come in and not bother the server with any more calls.

I'll post here once I find my own solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here's what I have which seems to work:

Basically I added flags in the session that are set on the ready callbacks of the two subscriptions. Then the `Deps.autorun` function listens for those Session values to be set and does the rest.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Meteor.subscribe("players", function(){
    console.log("players_loaded ");
    Session.set('players_loaded', true);
}); //linked to Meteor.users with user_id


Meteor.subscribe("games", function(){
   console.log("games_loaded ");
   Session.set('games_loaded', true); 
});  // each player has a game_id


Deps.autorun(function(){
    var gamesLoaded = Session.get('games_loaded');
    var playersLoaded = Session.get('players_loaded');
    if(gamesLoaded && playersLoaded && 
        (typeof Players !== 'undefined')  && (typeof Games !== 'undefined') ) {
        console.log("both loaded! ");
        //find the player from the user_id, find game from player.game_id
        var playerFromUser = Players.findOne({"user_id":Meteor.userId()});
        if(typeof playerFromUser !== 'undefined'){
          var getGame = Games.findOne(playerFromUser.game_id);
          if(typeof getGame !== 'undefined'){
              console.log("game found : " + getGame);
              //Do stuff with the game now that we have it
          }else{
              console.log("no game :(");
          }
        }else{
            console.log("no player :(");
        }
    }
});

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Session.set("title", "whatever else");
  Session.set("games_loaded", false);
  Session.set("players_loaded", false);
  console.log("DOM loaded");
});

}
```

Here's hoping I helped somebody.

Comment: Yep, that's how I'm doing it in our app.  There's also a `ready()` function on the subscription itself which you should be able to test against rather than using a separate Session variable but I've found the Session way to be more reliable for some reason:  http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe